# Highchart-ng not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Im trying to implement highcharts-ng to my project, but if fails during injecting.

I have highcharts-ng source file and also Ive added it into app.js:

```
return angular.module('xxx', ['ngRoute', 
                          'ngCookies',
                          'xxxxxxx',
                          'xxxxxxxx',
                          'xxxxxxxx',
                          'xxxxxxxx',
                          'xxxxxxxx',
                          'xxxxxxxx',
                          'highcharts-ng'
    ])
```

Also, I have it in require part of app.js:

```
define(['angular', 
        'highcharts-ng'
], function (angular) {
```

And finally, I have it ijected into directive:

'use strict';

```
define(['angular', 'jquery', '../module'], function(angular, $, module) {
    return module.directive('chart', ["highcharts-ng", function() {

    }]);
});
```

But, it will throw angular injector error:

> Unknown provider: highcharts-ngProvider <- highcharts-ng <-
>   chartDirective

Have no idea why, do you have any idea?

EDIT: angular.module("highcharts-ng") in app.js will return

```
Object {_invokeQueue: Array[2], _runBlocks: Array[0], requires: Array[0], name: "highcharts-ng"}
```

Comment: You sure the Highcharts js file is being imported correctly ?

Comment: Yes, its in sources part of the developer tools.

Comment: Are you able to setup live demo of that (on jsfiddle) ?

Comment: @MichalTakáč Have you solved it ?